# typedef enum in swift

Tags: enums, swift

I'm rewriting my Objective C application in Swift, and I have a question about enum's. In Objective C you would do;

```
typedef enum {
stopped,
running
} TimerState;
```

which returns the errors, `Consecutive Declarations on a line must be separated by ‘;’ — Expected declaration — Expected identifier in enum declaration`. I read some of the documentation about this and found that you don't put `typedef` before enum's anymore. So in swift I thought it would be:

```
enum {
stopped,
running
} TimerState;
```

But I do not know what to do with the TimerState, does that go inside the curly braces? What do i do. No smart ass comments either, please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

That is not how you declare an enum in Swift. You cannot simply list the values like you could in C. An enum could be accomplished in C with the following technique.

```
enum TimerState {
    stopped,
    running
};
```

In swift, you have to use the `case` keyword.

```
enum TimerState {
    case stopped
    case running
}
```

As for the `typedef`, there is a `typealias` in swift.

```
typealias SomeNewEnum = TimerState
```

**Edit:** If you want to assign a raw type to your enum, you can do so.

```
enum TimerState: Int {
        case stopped = 0
        case running // 1
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I already did!! I'm actually have one other question, do we have to add attributes like we do in @property's in Objective C? For example

property (nonatomic, strong)... how do we do that for IBOutlets in Swift? I was told that we don't have to but I don't know.

Comment: @istx25 You should ask another question instead asking here in the comments. It will get more attention and better answers.

Comment: @istx25 You do not need to worry about `nonatomic` in Swift. In most cases you also do not need to worry about `weak/strong` either. You can mark properties with the `@IBOutlet` prefix and they will automatically be set to `weak` as well. Just make sure you make them optional by appending `?` to the type name, as they can be nilled out.

Comment: Thanks @SiLo. StackoverFlow won't let me post another question for 90 minutes haha.

Comment: For Swift, once you have the enum defined, why would you then want to use `typealias`? What purpose does it have?

Comment: @Honey There would be none that I could think of. I was just trying to answer every question the OP had.

Comment: As for the first block of code that you wrote—in Objective-C. Why do we need `typedef` there? Is it because in Objective-C enums where not really considered as first class citizens but in Swift they are and you don't need the `typedef` anymore?