# Rewriting something in swift

Tags: swift

How would I rewrite the following Objective C line in Swift?

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, _UISiriWaveyViewMode) {
_UISiriWaveyViewModeSiri,
_UISiriWaveyViewModeDictation
};
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, what did you try? [SO Help center: How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) "Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague".

Comment: I'm just asking people with more experience how to write that, if you don't know how to move along. If you do please help.

Comment: No need to be rude. Also, you already asked a [*very* similar (but much better formulated) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147240/typedef-enum-in-swift) a month ago, and you did not accept any answer. It doesn't encourage people to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use enum keyword:

```
enum _UISiriWaveyViewMode : Int {
    case _UISiriWaveyViewModeSiri = 0
    case _UISiriWaveyViewModeDictation
}
```

If it needs to be a NSInteger enum replace Int with NSInteger.

Comment: In Swift you would define the cases as `Siri`, `Dictation` because enums are namespaced.

Comment: Could I have your twitter, Greg? I have some additional questions that I would like to have answered. Maybe outside of Stackoverflow.